# Derivative of a neat function

Tags: calculus

Let $\phi$ be a "neat"(I don't even know what that is ) function of 2 arguments,defined in the whole plane and $f(x,y,z)=\phi\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z}\right)$. Prove that it is true for $f$

$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =0$$

Comment: Might be.Can you show with your remark how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have miscopied the question or there simply is an error in it.

First of all, neat function here probably means a function with continuous partial derivatives. Second, we should have

$$f(x,y,z) = \phi(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z})$$

This function is homogeneous of degree $0$, as a consequence, [Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html) applies and

$$x\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0 f = 0 \; .$$